# printing values along a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements, innerhtml

```
function sumOfMulti(){
var sum = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++){
    if (x % 3 === 0 || x % 5 === 0)
    {
      document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = x;
      sum += x;  //sum = sum + x
    }
  }
  alert(sum);
};
```

hi guys, I want to print each and every value of x which meets the condition in the loop

but it only gives me the last value of them

Javascript does't work this way?
will I have to store the values in array first? =(
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign it with keeping the old content.

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += x + '<br>';
```

```js
function sumOfMulti() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        if (x % 3 === 0 || x % 5 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += x + '<br>';
            sum += x;
        }
    }
}

sumOfMulti();
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

The same with creating new nodes.

```js
function sumOfMulti() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        if (x % 3 === 0 || x % 5 === 0) {
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(document.createTextNode(x));
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            sum += x;
        }
    }
}

sumOfMulti();
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: absolutely understood about the overwriting part